# Javascript jquery - Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to test a login web service by posting some xml to log in and it's returing this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = $.parseXML("<authenticationDetail><userName>username</userName><password>passw</password></authenticationDetail>");
  var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/thelogin.ws";
   $.ajax({ 
        data: data,
        type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/xml", 
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) { // callback called when data is received 
              alert("success to post");
        },
        error: function() { // callback called when error
              alert("fail to post");
        }
  });
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add a minimal reproduction within a snippet and where does the error get fired.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing :

```
var data = $.parseXML("<authenticationDetail><userName>username</userName><password>passw</password></authenticationDetail>");
```

To :

```
var data = "<authenticationDetail><userName>username</userName><password>passw</password></authenticationDetail>";
```

You're sending XML, not parsed XML.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `dataType` to `xml`, but you're doing `$.parseXML` and sending the parsed XML (an object).

```
var data = $.parseXML("<authenticationDetail><userName>username</userName><password>passw</password></authenticationDetail>");
```

`data` is an object, not a valid XML string.

JQuery needs the unparsed XML string for this request to work.

So just omit the `$.parseXML` part and it should work.